# How to return an object pointer with conditional expression?

Tags: c++, memory, smart-pointers, return-value-optimization

According to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LFv7XwgsdLY&t=1620s 25:40

`class Foo` should be retured 2 ways:

- with if

```cpp
if(condition) 
   return foo1 
else 
    return foo2;
```

- with conditional expression

```cpp
return condition ? food(foo1) : std::move(foo2);
```

what if `Foo` is a `unique_ptr` and I want to check if `Foo` is not nullptr then return `foo` and if it is a nullptr return `nullptr`. Lets forget for now that someone might want to delete that pointer.

which way is the proper one?

```cpp
Foo* getFoo()
{
    //get because foo is a unique ptr
    return foo ? foo.get() : nullptr;
}
```

```cpp
Foo* getFoo()
{
    return foo ? std::move(foo.get()) : nullptr;
}
```

Comment: If `foo` does not own an object, `foo.get()` returns `nullptr`. `return foo ? foo.get() : nullptr;` thus does not make any sense, since you can simply write `return foo.get();` instead.

Comment: Also, note that `std::move(foo.get())` does not make any sense either, since `foo.get()` returns a pointer by value. You are just making an rvalue from an rvalue. Moreover, copying and moving the contents of fundamental types, such as pointers, have the same effect (there are no copy/move constructors/assignment operators involved).

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any sort of branching.  You can just use

```
Foo* getFoo()
{
    return foo.get();
}
```

This works because [`get`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/get) will return `nullptr` if `foo` holds a `nullptr`.

Comment: @BrodaJarek3 Same thing.  If it's `nullptr`, you can just return it.

Comment: You wouldn't write `if (x == 0) return 0; else return x;` for an integer, so why do it for a pointer? The video is about returning one of two different objects, not returning one object which may take different values.